# Как сделать preloader для сменяющегося src в iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Меняю кнопками src в iframe и хочу сделать для него preloader.
Но он пропадает не дожидаясь загрузки страницы(отслеживаю через DevTools браузера).
Помогите пожалуйста.

```js
// Сбрасывает iframe и подставляет новую ссылку из input=radio в него 
$('input[name="input_radio"]').click(function() {
  $("iframe#main_iframe").removeAttr('onload');
  $("iframe#main_iframe").attr('src', '');
  $('iframe#main_iframe').css('display', 'none');
  $(".preloader").css('display', 'block');
  setTimeout(function() {
    let ifsrc = $('input[name="input_radio"]:checked').val()
    theme = `${ifsrc}`;
    $('iframe#main_iframe').attr('src', theme);
  }, 500);
});
// Сбрасывает iframe и подставляет новую ссылку из input=radio в него 


// Действия после загрузки iframe
document.getElementById('main_iframe').onload = function() {
  $(".preloader").css('display', 'none');
  $('iframe#main_iframe').css('display', 'block');
}
// Действия после загрузки iframe
```

```css
.preloader {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="input_radio" value="" id="id1">
<label for="id1">Пустой</label>

<input type="radio" name="input_radio" value="https://488542.annacdn.cc/hxhCnBZvbnnS/tv-series/10579" id="id2">
<label for="id2">Долго загружающаяся страница</label>

<input type="radio" name="input_radio" value="https://videocdn.tv/" id="id3">
<label for="id3">Сайт с фильмами(не реклама)</label>



<iframe src="" id="main_iframe"></iframe>
<div class="preloader" id="preloader">
  <p>Load...</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну вы, блин, даёте! .) Нагородили...
Переписал вам всю внутрянку на логичную, не трогая html. Лишь добавил подкласс 'hide' прелоадеру. Технически моему наброску кода даже не требуется идентификатор. Но мало ли у вас на странице есть ещё какие-нибудь 'iframe'

```js
$('input[name="input_radio"]').click(function() {
    let id = $('input[name="input_radio"]:checked').attr('id');
    let source = $('input[name="input_radio"]:checked').attr('value');
    $('iframe').attr({src:source,id:id});

    // 1. включаем показ прелоадера меняя убирая из него часть класса 'hide'
    let preloader = $("#preloader")
    if ( preloader.hasClass('hide') ) {
        preloader.removeClass('hide');
    }
 
   // замените на поиск элемента по #id, если что
    $('iframe').on('load', function() {
     // 2. возвращаем прелоадеру 'hide', как только iframe загрузился
         preloader.addClass('hide');
    });
});
```

```css
iframe {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 320px;
    width: 480px;
    border: solid 1px #eee;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="input_radio" value="" id="id1">
<label for="id1">Пустой</label>
<input type="radio" name="input_radio" value="https://488542.annacdn.cc/hxhCnBZvbnnS/tv-series/10579" id="id2">
<label for="id2">Долго загружающаяся страница</label>
<input type="radio" name="input_radio" value="https://videocdn.tv/" id="id3">
<label for="id3">Сайт с фильмами(не реклама)</label>
<br>
<iframe src="" id="main_iframe" scrolling="no"></iframe>

<div class="preloader hide" id="preloader">
  <p>Load...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Ваш код работает